# Updating values in a yaml file using snakeYaml

Tags: java, struts2, yaml, struts2-jquery

Is there any way to **edit/delete** the values in a YAMLfile using java.

I'm using struts2-jquery-grid where the data will be populated from YAML file. Now, If I edit the field(s), it should be saved in YAML file. I am able to read the value from and write the values to a file in YAML format using *yaml.load() and yaml.dump()* respectively. But, I don't have any idea to do edit and delete the specific field.

I've gone through http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Dumping_YAML link where I read that we can use *template processor* and other options like *defining order of java bean property, comments to make ease of yaml*. But all those doesn't make any sense to me.

Here is my code to **serialize** the list of object called *assumption* here. In **gridModel.add(assumption);**, I'm storing the values of class Assumption(bean class with fetters and setters) to the list here in *gridModel*.

```
       gridModel.add(assumption);

       try {

        FileWriter pr=new FileWriter("D:/yaml.yaml");

        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();

         options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
        String output=yaml.dump(gridModel);//,Tag.MAP, null);
        pr.write(output);
        System.out.print(pr.toString());
        System.out.println();

        pr.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

***The outout I'm getting in a file called yaml.yaml as:***

- !!com.example.Assumption
  column1: '1'
  column2: Balwant
  column3: SPJ
  column4: rerer
  column5: null
- !!com.example.Assumption
  column1: ''
  column2: Vikas
  column3: RNC
  column4: erer
  column5: null
- !!com.example.Assumption
  column1: '3'
  column2: ''
  column3: PNBE
  column4: erer
  column5: null
- !!com.example.Assumption
  column1: '4'
  column2: Diwakar
  column3: BGP
  column4: rerer
  column5: null
- !!com.example.Assumption
  column1: '5'
  column2: Ajay
  column3: Godda
  column4: ''
  column5: null

For **De-serialization** the code is:

```
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/yaml.yaml"));
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    for (Object data : yaml.loadAll(input))
        System.out.println("Data:"+data);
```

***The output to the console is :***

Data:[Assumption [column1=1, column2=Balwant, column3=SPJ, column4=rerer, column5=null], Assumption [column1=, column2=Vikas, column3=RNC, column4=erer, column5=null], Assumption [column1=3, column2=, column3=PNBE, column4=erer, column5=null], Assumption [column1=4, column2=Diwakar, column3=BGP, column4=rerer, column5=null], Assumption [column1=5, column2=Ajay, column3=Godda, column4=, column5=null]]

I'm new to yaml and struts2. So, please answer a clean solution. Correct me, if I'm wrong while describing the requirement. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think editing is basically: read -> modify -> write. Can you do it this way?

Comment: You're right. As I've mentioned above that I'm using a jqGrid grid.So, I can read using grid, modify as well but the modification I want to reflect to the yaml file.

Comment: Show java code where you handle modification from jqGrid.

Comment: This is completely unclear. Imaging you do not have a YAML file, but a pre-formatted text file. What is the difference ?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I'm updating the question with code please refer that.

Comment: @Andrey Please refer the code I've posted with question now.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think to edit is to overwrite the existing yaml. We need to get the values from grid and overwrite ti to the existing one.